# session variable asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How I can Clean the session variable,  which hold file path while load the asp page(AddFiles.aspx)  first time only?

Answer (score 4):

```
if (!IsPostback)
{
   Session["FilePath"] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the PostBack:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    Session["yourSessionName"] = "";
}
```